# How to install python library in VSCode and how to import them?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How to install python library such as 'dash' which are not installed by default in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Have you tried using `pip` (probably from VSC's terminal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Python extension provided by Microsoft, then add a python virtual environment as  described in  [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) :

```
python -m venv .venv
```

Select the virtual env (bottom left corner of VS Code) and open a terminal with VS Code. Make sure the script activate from the virtual env is executed (your terminal should append (.venv) notation) and import your library with pip install :

```
pip install dash
```